# Array value changes inexplicably?

Tags: javascript

So, started porting one of my C# programs to Javascript, just because it felt like a good way to get familiar with it. But I'm running into issues with my arrays; they are inside objects, and they keep strangely changing, when they should not.

I'm checking the *_in* and *_out* values twice from the first object, RotorSetI; first after creating the object and again after the RotorSetII object.

The first check, shows *_out* has the value it was given. But on the second check, it has changed to the *_out* value of RotorSetII.

I'll post the code bits below but I'm completely baffled. **What am I doing wrong?**

```
var RotorSetI = (function()
{
    var app = {},

    _in  = new Array("P","4","K","Ö","7","M","T","U","G","Q","V","1","J","H","2","Ä","S","I","Y","D","R","X","E","N","W","8","C","B","L","3","5","0","6","Z","F","9","O","A");
    _out = new Array("J","K","X","9","U","C","T","G","4","H","F","B","I","8","D","R","3","7","L","V","Ö","Y","N","1","W","0","S","A","6","Ä","Q","O","Z","P","E","2","5","M");

    app.setIn = function()
    {
        return _in;
    }

    app.setOut = function()
    {
        return _out;
    }

    return app;
}());

console.log(RotorSetI.setIn());
console.log(RotorSetI.setOut()); /* <-- Still shows the right value */

/**
 * ROTOR SET II
 */
var RotorSetII = (function()
{
    var app = {},

    _in  = new Array("E","7","2","Ö","S","N","U","O","J","B","I","L","D","M","H","F","6","Q","P","0","Z","C","T","V","3","W","4","5","1","Y","X","9","Ä","K","8","R","A","G");
    _out = new Array("Ä","6","V","S","H","B","K","F","N","P","M","X","C","W","I","5","Ö","0","4","3","Q","Y","J","Z","D","L","T","9","O","E","U","R","8","2","G","1","A","7");

    app.setIn = function()
    {
        return _in;
    }

    app.setOut = function()
    {
        return _out;
    }

    return app;
}());


console.log(RotorSetI.setIn());
console.log(RotorSetI.setOut()); /* <-- Value has mysterious changed! */
```

And here is the output:

```
["P", "4", "K", "Ö", "7", "M", "T", "U", "G", "Q", "V", "1", "J", "H", "2", "Ä", "S", "I", "Y", "D", "R", "X", "E", "N", "W", "8", "C", "B", "L", "3", "5", "0", "6", "Z", "F", "9", "O", "A"]
["J", "K", "X", "9", "U", "C", "T", "G", "4", "H", "F", "B", "I", "8", "D", "R", "3", "7", "L", "V", "Ö", "Y", "N", "1", "W", "0", "S", "A", "6", "Ä", "Q", "O", "Z", "P", "E", "2", "5", "M"]
["P", "4", "K", "Ö", "7", "M", "T", "U", "G", "Q", "V", "1", "J", "H", "2", "Ä", "S", "I", "Y", "D", "R", "X", "E", "N", "W", "8", "C", "B", "L", "3", "5", "0", "6", "Z", "F", "9", "O", "A"]
["Ä", "6", "V", "S", "H", "B", "K", "F", "N", "P", "M", "X", "C", "W", "I", "5", "Ö", "0", "4", "3", "Q", "Y", "J", "Z", "D", "L", "T", "9", "O", "E", "U", "R", "8", "2", "G", "1", "A", "7"]
```

Comment: It's because you're reusing the global variable `_out`.

Comment: You forgot to `var _in, _out;`

Comment: That wouldn't have happened with one `var` per variable.

Comment: @FelixKling This also wouldn't happen in strict mode.

Comment: @MikeC: That's even better :)

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" beside the `;` instead of `,` you're trying to getting familiar with JavaScript by porting C# code :-)

Comment: @Paolo Porting was a poor choice of words; more like just recycling a an idea for learning project that I did first in C#, into Javascript. Good and meaningful idea are hard to come by. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @FelixKling Not familiar with strict mode. But thanks for the tip, I'll look into it.

Comment: @Cory seriously: nothing wrong with that. But it's my belief that when learning a new language it's important to be not-conditioned by languages we already know. If you already did that project in C# you'll be tempted to "translate" the original code. Instead of doing it the JavaScript way.

Comment: @Paolo Sure, though that's always the case I think. The same way, when I first learned PHP and moved on, kept trying to do the things the PHP way. Hopefully C# will wear off me eventually, as I get more a hang of how to write javascript :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `,` at the end of your `_in` declaration. You're accidentally creating a global called `_out` and overwriting it in `RotorSetII`.

```
var app = {},
    _in = new Array(...), // <--
    _out = new Array(...);
```

As a general pro-tip, it's considered good practice in Javascript to declare arrays using array literals instead of the `Array` constructor.

```
_in = ["P", ...]
```

Comment: Ahhhh.... yeah, I see it. The article that showed me this way of doing objects only had one private property in its example, which is why I did not know about the comma :)